# How to use a key listener?

Tags: raspbian, hardware, python, servo

Ok, at the moment I am working on adding motors to a lego tank that I have. I have one servo in the front to steer and another motor in the rear that will make it go forwards and backwards. i have them both hooked up to a pwm controller from adafruit. I have used their python library and I have some code to move the motors. Now I just am wondering how I can make it so that when the program is running if I hit "w" it will go forward, no having to press enter. Sorry if this seems like a simple problem, I am a beginner programmer.

Comment: You'll probably get better help if you rephrase this in terms of code (like, show the code, refer to the library docs, etc) and *ask on a python forum*.

Comment: Using Lego to learn to program is awesome, that's how they taught us at uni, and it works a treat. If you can link me to the man page I'd be more than happy to have a crack at it for you.

Answer (score 1):

The full answer is here:
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292095/polling-the-keyboard-in-python

The short answer is:

```
import sys
import select

def heardEnter():
    i,o,e = select.select([sys.stdin],[],[],0.0001)
    for s in i:
        if s == sys.stdin:
            input = sys.stdin.readline()
            return True
    return False
```

You will need to generalize this for steering.  `sys.stdlin.readline` is looking to read everything up to the enter key (newline)  You probably just want to do `sys.stdin.read(1)` to get a single keystroke.